# can I somehow store a variable amount of characters in an string array?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INITIAL_SIZE 3



int main()
{
    size_t arraySize = INITIAL_SIZE;
    size_t numsEnteredSoFar = 0;
    int* myArray = malloc(sizeof(*myArray)*arraySize);  
    if (myArray == NULL) exit(-1);  

    while(1)
    {
        int curEntry;
        char ch=0;
        if (scanf("%d", &curEntry) == 1)
    
    
        {
            ch = fgetc (stdin);
            
            myArray[numsEnteredSoFar++] = curEntry;
        

            if (numsEnteredSoFar == arraySize)
            {
            
            arraySize += INITIAL_SIZE;
            int* temp = realloc(myArray, arraySize*sizeof(*myArray));
            if (temp == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
                exit(-1);
            }
            else
            {
            
                myArray = temp;
            }
        }
    }
     
    if(ch == 10)
    {
        
        break;
    }
    if(myArray[numsEnteredSoFar]>10000 || myArray[numsEnteredSoFar]<-10000)
{
   
   exit (-1);
}
    }



 int i,  found=0, pos=0,max=0, min=0,nm=0,mez=0;

  float pk, pz, ps, pl, prumer;
  char space=32;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < numsEnteredSoFar; i++) 
  {
  
      nm++;
    if(i >3)
  {
    exit (-1);  
  }
  }
    if(myArray[i]>=3 && myArray[i]<=69 )
    {
        if(nm==1)
        {
        printf("XXXXX\n");
        printf("X   X\n");
        printf("X   X\n");
        printf("X   X\n");
        printf("XXXXX\n");
        }
        if(nm==2)
        { 
        
            for(i=0; i<myArray[1]; i++)
            {
              mez++;
            printf("X");
            }
                 printf("\n");
          
        for (i=0; i<myArray[0]-2; i++)
        {
         printf("X");
         for(i=0;i<mez-2;i++)
         {
         printf(" ");
         }
         }
        printf("X");
         printf("\n");  
     
     
            for(i=0; i<myArray[1]; i++)
            {
            printf("X");   
            }
             printf("\n");
         }
        }
        



    printf("%d\n", nm);
     printf("%d\n", mez-2);
    printf("%d\n", myArray[0]);

    for (i = 0; i < numsEnteredSoFar; i++)
     {
       if (i)
       printf (", ");
       printf ("%i", myArray[i]);
     }
 
  printf ("\n");  









 free(myArray);
}
```

first number is height second is width

any clue on what am I missing?
its supposed to output this

[image]

but it outputs this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuwe4.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuwe4.png)

I need the line 2 copied and printed below so it would make a rectangle

my idea was this

```
printf("X%sX", ch)//where "ch" would be variable number of spaces
```

continuation:[how do you make a isosceles triangle using for loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69959971/how-do-you-make-a-isosceles-triangle-using-for-loops)

Comment: There are no string arrays in the code you posted.

Comment: please edit the question and post a [mcve]

Comment: if `mez = 0` and you're checking for `i < mez - 2` then it will always be false because `mez - 2= -2`. This will cause the next line of your code being ignored. That looks like not the only thing wrong with your code though... also you're using the same variable `i` in your second loop, I don't think you meant to do that. Maybe change it into some `j` instead.

Comment: ok I post it whole then

Comment: The  use  of `i` between the loops is a really really bad idea. You can store between `0` and `n` characters in any character array where `n` is the number of elements in the array (or between `0` and `n-1` if you want to treat the array as a string) Instead of a 2nd loop just of `if (i == 0 || i == myarray[0] - 1) { putchar ('x') }`

Comment: no I need a new string array or something, which I could configure and put it between the X's so it would make multiple spaces, if you follow

Comment: Avoid changing a question like this. (was Box, now House)  It renders all comments and answers before your edit not make sense any more. Better to revert this edit and ask the roof question as a new and separate question. I'll watch for it. That way all comments and answers related to your Box question still make sense.

Comment: true, forgot someone else might use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the rows one-by-one. You have to print the full line of `'X'`s on the first and last row. For all middle rows, you want to print `'X'` as the first and last character, and then spaces in between.

You can lay your loops out as follows (there is more than one way to structures the test conditions), e.g.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define NELEM 5     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {
  
  for (int i = 0; i < NELEM; i++) {       /* for NELEM rows */
    for (int j = 0; j < NELEM; j++) {     /* for NELEM columns */
      if (i == 0 || i == NELEM - 1)       /* 1st or last row */
        putchar ('X');
      else {                              /* middle-rows */
        if (j == 0 || j == NELEM - 1)     /* 1st and last char */
          putchar ('X');
        else
          putchar (' ');                  /* rest */
      }
    }
    putchar ('\n');
  }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/xbox
XXXXX
X   X
X   X
X   X
XXXXX
```

Let me know if this is what you are after. If not, I can help further.

A shorter, but less readable version using a *ternary* could be written as:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define NELEM 5     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {
  
  for (int i = 0; i < NELEM; i++) {       /* for NELEM rows */
    for (int j = 0; j < NELEM; j++) {     /* for NELEM columns */
      /* 1st or last row/col 'X' otherwise ' ' */
      putchar ((i == 0 || i == NELEM - 1 || j == 0 || j == NELEM - 1) ?
              'X' : ' ');
    }
    putchar ('\n');
  }
}
```

(same output)

There are many ways to skin-the-cat.

Comment: oh nice, I am gonna have to make a roof and a fence aswell but I hope that wont be hard now thx to you I shall contact you if I get stuck tho if you dont mind, thx

Comment: Sounds good. Good luck with your roof and fence. Remember take it *line-by-line* from top to bottom and determine what needs to be printed on each line. Add the necessary test conditions to output what is needed when.

Comment: yea it will take me while to comprehend what have you done :D

Comment: Just go line by line through the first code (the 2nd is less readable). The `i` loop loops over each row, the `j` loop loops over each column (character). You can make it more readable by changing `i` to `row` everywhere and `j` to `col` -- may help. Take all the time you need. The important point is that you understand why the code works and why it was written that way. It doesn't matter how long it takes to get there.

Comment: Additionally,  you don't need an array at all. You are simply outputing either an `'X'` or `' '` (space). So you use `putchar()` to output a single character at a time. If you needed to store those characters in a 2D array, you would fill the array exactly the same, only assigning a character-at-a-time to the array instead of printing it.